# Application is crashing in my iOS simulator when I try to draw second plot in core-plot graph

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, core-plot, uipagecontrol

`

```
    #import "TUTSimpleScatterPlot.h"
    #import "CPDConstants.h"
    #import "CPDStockPriceStore.h"

    @implementation TUTSimpleScatterPlot

    @synthesize hostView = _hostingView;  
    @synthesize graph = _graph;  
    @synthesize graphEmpActualWeightData = _graphEmpActualWeightData;  
    @synthesize graphEmpGoalWeightData = _graphEmpGoalWeightData;

    // Initialise the scatter plot in the provided hosting view with the provided data.  
    // The data array should contain NSValue objects each representing a CGPoint.   

    -(id)initWithHostingView:(CPTGraphHostingView *)hostingView andEmpActualWeight:(NSMutableArray *)valuesEmpActualWeight andEmpGoalWeight:(NSMutableArray *)valuesEmpGoalWeight
    {

       self = [super init];  
       if ( self != nil ) {  
            self.hostView = hostingView;   
            self.graphEmpActualWeightData = valuesEmpActualWeight;    
            self.graphEmpGoalWeightData = valuesEmpGoalWeight;   
            self.graph = nil;  
        }   
        return self;  
    }   
     #pragma mark - Chart behavior   
    -(void)initPlot {    
        [self configureGraph];   
        [self configurePlots];   
        [self configureAxes];   
    }    



    -(void)configureGraph {    
        // 1 - Create the graph    
        CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];   
        [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];   
        self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;    
        // 2 - Set graph title    
        NSString *title = @"Body weight actual and goal";    
        graph.title = title;    
        // 3 - Create and set text style    
        CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];    
        titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];    
        titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";   
        titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;   
        graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;   
        graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;   
        graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);   
        // 4 - Set padding for plot area   
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:30.0f];   
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:30.0f];   
        // 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space   
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;   
        plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;   
        }   

    -(void)configurePlots {   
        // 1 - Get graph and plot space   
        CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;   
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;   
            // 2 - Create the two plots   
        CPTScatterPlot *actualPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];   
        actualPlot.dataSource = self;   
        actualPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolActual;   
        CPTColor *actualColor = [CPTColor redColor];   
        [graph addPlot:actualPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];   
            CPTScatterPlot *goalPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];   
        goalPlot.dataSource = self;   
        goalPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGoal;   
        CPTColor *goalColor = [CPTColor greenColor];   
        [graph addPlot:goalPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];   
        // 3 - Set up plot space   
        [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:actualPlot,nil]];      
        CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];      
        [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];      
        plotSpace.xRange = xRange;      
            CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];    
        [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];     
        plotSpace.yRange = yRange;      
            // 4 - Create styles and symbols   
        CPTMutableLineStyle *actualLineStyle = [actualPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];   
        actualLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;   
        actualLineStyle.lineColor = actualColor;      
            actualPlot.dataLineStyle = actualLineStyle;   
        CPTMutableLineStyle *actualSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];   
        actualSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = actualColor;      
            CPTPlotSymbol *actualSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol hexagonPlotSymbol];   
        actualSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:actualColor];   
        actualSymbol.lineStyle = actualSymbolLineStyle;   
        actualSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);   
            actualPlot.plotSymbol = actualSymbol;   
            CPTMutableLineStyle *goalLineStyle = [goalPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];   
        goalLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;   
        goalLineStyle.lineColor = goalColor;   
        goalPlot.dataLineStyle = goalLineStyle;   
        CPTMutableLineStyle *goalSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];   
        goalSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = goalColor;   
        CPTPlotSymbol *goalSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];   
        goalSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:goalColor];   
        goalSymbol.lineStyle = goalSymbolLineStyle;   
        goalSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);   
        goalPlot.plotSymbol = goalSymbol;   
    }   


    -(void)configureAxes {   
        // 1 - Create styles   
        CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];   
        axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];   
        axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";   
        axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;   
        CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];   
        axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;   
        axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];   
        CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];   
        axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];   
        axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";   
        axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;   
        CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];   
        tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];   
        tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;   
        CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];   
        tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];   
        tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;   
        // 2 - Get axis set   
        CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;   
        // 3 - Configure x-axis   
        CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;   
        x.title = @"Weeks ->";   
        x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;   
        x.titleOffset = 15.0f;   
        x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;   
        x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;   
        x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;   
        x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;   
        x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;   
        x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;   //commented by me   
       // x.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;   
        NSInteger xmajorIncrement = 2;   
        NSInteger xminorIncrement = 1;   
        //CGFloat dateCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];   
        CGFloat dateCount = 20;   
        NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];   
        NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];   
        NSInteger i = 0;   
        for (NSString *date in [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth]) {   
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];   
            CGFloat location = i++;   
           // CGFloat location = ++i;   
            label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);   
            label.offset = x.majorTickLength;   
            if (label) {   
                [xLabels addObject:label];   
                [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];   
            }   
        }   
        x.axisLabels = xLabels;   
        x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;   
        // 4 - Configure y-axis   
        CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;   
        y.title = @"Weight ->";   
        y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;   
        y.titleOffset = -40.0f;  //commented by me   
        y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;   
        y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;   
        y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;   
        y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;   
        y.labelOffset = 16.0f;   
        y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;   
        y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;   
        y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;   
        y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;   
        NSInteger majorIncrement = 40;   
        NSInteger minorIncrement = 20;   
        CGFloat yMax = 300.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price   
        NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];   
        NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];   
        NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];   
        for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {   
            NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;   
            if (mod == 0) {   
                CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];   
                NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);   
                label.tickLocation = location;   
                label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;   
                if (label) {   
                    [yLabels addObject:label];   
                }   
                [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];   
            } else {   
                [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];   
            }   
        }   
        y.axisLabels = yLabels;   
        y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;   
        y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;   
    }   



    #pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods   
    -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {   
        //return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];   
        return 20;   

    }   


-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSInteger valueCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
  //  NSValue *value = [self.graphData objectAtIndex:index];
 //   CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];

    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            if (index < valueCount) {
               //if( [plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolGoal] == YES)
                return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            }

            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolActual] == YES ) {
                //return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] objectAtIndex:index];

                if(index < [_graphEmpActualWeightData count]){
                  // return [_graphEmpActualWeightData objectAtIndex:index];
                    return   (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[[_graphEmpActualWeightData objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue]];
                }
                else{
                //    return (NSNumber *) nil;
                }

            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolGoal] == YES) {
                //return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG]
            //return [_graphEmpGoalWeightData objectAtIndex:index];
                return   (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[[_graphEmpGoalWeightData objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue]];
            }
            break;
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}

// This does the actual work of creating the plot if we don't already have a graph object.
-(void)initialisePlot
{
    // Start with some simple sanity checks before we kick off
    if ( (self.hostView == nil) || (self.graphEmpGoalWeightData == nil)  ) {
        NSLog(@"TUTSimpleScatterPlot: Cannot initialise plot without hosting view or data.");
        return;
    }

    if ( self.graph != nil ) {
        NSLog(@"TUTSimpleScatterPlot: Graph object already exists.");
        return;
    }
    [self initPlot];

}
```

`Hi friends,
I have been struggling with this problem since yesterday. Need your help desperately.
I'm new to core plot and have been facing a crash issue when I try to draw a second plot in the graph. I'm getting different different reasons each time. some of them are pasted below.

1)*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM numberOfRecordsForPlot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x726adc0'

2)EXC_BAD_ACCESS

3)*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayerArray numberOfRecordsForPlot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x769f5b0'

4)*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDecimalNumber numberOfRecordsForPlot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x726adc0'

I'm really not getting what went wrong in my code. It is working fine when I

Comment: Have you tried debugging in xcode, and check that call stack when your code crash? By doing so you can pinpoint which line in your code causes the crash

Comment: Hi Gerrytan, Thanks for your response. I observed that the crash is happening when i assign the datasource as self to the second plot. goalPlot.datasource = self; Crash is happening at the time of accessing the data. Though i hardcoded the numberOfRecordsForPlot( ) as return 20 but still its crashing. Its happening only for the second plot. Kindly try to address my issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you change the plot `dataSource` anywhere else in your code? If the code you posted works for one plot, it should work for others, too.

Comment: @Eric, I didn't change the datasource anywhere else in the programme. Yes It is working for one plot but its crashing for the second plot. Not sure why its happening. Please try to address in your free time. Thanks